# What's the best way to troubleshoot a cron that doesn't fire?

Tags: cron

Continuing from [a Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295611/how-can-i-troubleshoot-why-my-php-script-wont-work-in-cron-when-it-does-from-the), I've got a .sh that tries to (1) run a script that sets environment vars and then (2) runs a php script.

The crontab entry (have tried with and without `>>` output):

```
 */1 * * * * /home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/ec2-api-tools/php/doQueue.sh >> /home/user/output.txt
```

The script, doQueue.sh (running this by hand works):

```
#/bin/sh
. ./environment.sh
php process_queue.php
```

The environment.sh (again, works by hand):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "running environment"
PATH=$EC2_HOME/bin:$PATH
EC2_HOME=/home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/ec2-api-tools
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/ec2-api-tools/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PWD=/home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/ec2-api-tools
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/ec2-api-tools/pk-hash.pem
EC2_CERT=/home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/ec2-api-tools/cert-hash.pem
```

I've tried variations using `sh` and `.` to no avail. What's the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is this in /var/spool/cron/crontabs or /etc/cron.d/ (the latter requires the user to run the job as)? Have you tried putting debug statements in doQueue.sh to get some output to verify that it's running?

Comment: So what I was missing was that I needed to "export" the vars into the environment. Please change this comment to a response and I'll pick your answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` or `/etc/cron.d/` (the latter requires the user to run the job as)?

Have you tried putting debug statements in doQueue.sh to get some output to verify that it's running?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure crontab file ends with a newline

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/sh
. ./environment.sh
```

!

And what is the CWD when the script runs? Try specifying the absolute path to environment.sh

That would explain why the cron job doesn't actually work, but not why it never fires at all.

By default, cron mails the local user with the output of jobs and error messages - have you checked this?

Are you sure that the job exists in the cron file? (i.e. what do you see when you type in 'crontab -l' at the prompt).

HTH

C.

Comment: ....and check that crond is running and the user is allowed to run cron jobs of course